# How to remove documents from a single collection that exceeds a certain limit

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently replacing a big MySQL join-table with a MongoDB collection. One of the queries performed on the old MySQL table was limiting the amount of records for a certain key (exclusive join on a LIMIT ORDER BY record-set). But how to do this in MongoDB?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Basically, are you wanting to only allow 100 documents with `somefield = 1`, and another 100 for `somefield = 2`?

Comment: Indeed, this is what we want...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort({key:1})` to do order by (use -1 instead of 1 for descending order) and `limit(N)` to limit the returned result to N documents.

If instead you want to get all except the top N documents you would use:

```
   db.collection.find({user:"X"}).sort({key:-1}).skip(1000)
```

This will return all the documents except the top 1000 sorted by key.

Comment: Yes, but can you query and delete the excessive records server-side?

Comment: you asked about limiting query. what do you mean by "delete excessive records"?

Comment: It is about deleting the 'rest'. For example, in case of a collection with let's say a compound index on user_id and image_id, consider I only want to maintain 1000 records for every user.

Comment: So, you don't want to select top 1000 records, but instead all except top 1000 records? What you do instead of limit is use skip.  So .sort({...}).skip(1000) will give you all but the first 1000 records by whatever criteria.

Comment: And then I can do that in the delete. Awesome. thanks, you should be posting that as an answer!